# Show that $V_{a}^{b}(X_\mathbb{Q}) = +\infty$ on any interval [a, b]

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I'm self-studying the theory of functions of bounded variations from the book of Neal Carother (*Real Analysis*) and need some help with this problem:

> Show that $V_{a}^{b}(X_\mathbb{Q}) = +\infty$ on any interval [a, b].

In the previous chapter the author defines $X_\mathbb{Q}$, the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$, by $X_\mathbb{Q}(x) = 1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $X_\mathbb{Q}(x) = 0$ if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

---

**My thoughts:**

Let $P_n$ be a random partition of $(n + 1)$ points of the closed interval $[a, b]$. That is
$$P_n = [a, x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n-1}, b].$$
The total variation of the characteristic equation of $\mathbb{Q}$ over the interval $[a, b]$ can be written as
$$V_{a}^{b}(X_\mathbb{Q}) = V_{a}^{x_1}(X_\mathbb{Q}) + V_{x_1}^{x_2}(X_\mathbb{Q}) + ... + V_{x_{n - 1}}^{b}(X_\mathbb{Q})$$
but I don't know how to prove that this sum tends to infinity.

Comment: Hint: how about if the partition has rational and nonrational points?

Comment: Just to get started thinking about it (always a good idea) consider $0<r<1$ where $r$ is irrational.  Then $V_{0}^{1}(X_\mathbb{Q}) \geq |f(r)-f(0)|+ |f(1)-f(r)|=2$.  But if $0<r<s<t< 1$ where $r$ and $t$ are irrational and $s$ is rational then $V_{0}^{1}(X_\mathbb{Q}) \geq |f(r)-f(0)|+ |f(s)-f(r)| + \dots =4$.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Thank you for this intuitive and clear example. Since the total variation of $X_\mathbb{Q}$ is defined as the supremum being taken over all partitions of [a, b] this infinite sum ultimately tends to infinity by your demonstration. Is it sufficient to say this?

Comment: The usual way to prove this is to show that for any integer $N$ you can choose a partition that will demonstrate that $V_a^b(X_Q)\geq N$.  There is no "infinite sum" here since partitions are finite.